# Add an existing list item to another list

Tags: c#, list, oop

Okay, to explain this I'll try to summarise what I'm doing

At some point I create a list of items in a class 'Supplier'. In this example a list of parts is added to the list of Suppliers that exists in the masterclass.

At some point, I then want to choose a specific part to be added to a job (job class), this part has already been created, I would simply like to take the part and add it to the job.

That part has been added using this:
'Previous to this, the supplier has been selected'

```
Class Supplier
public void AddParts( int PartNum, string PartName, string PartDescription, decimal      Cost, decimal CostWithVAT, decimal Price, short Quantity)
{          
    m_partUsed.Add(new Part(PartNum, PartName, PartDescription, Cost, Price, Quantity));         
}
```

Here is how I intend to implement this:

```
   private void btnAddJobPart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Select the job that the part is to be added too
        string selectedJob = cboJobPartRef.Text;
        List<Job> foundJob = Program.AuspexDo.SelectJob(selectedJob);

        //For the job found
        foreach (Job j in foundJob)
        {
            //Select the supplier
            string selectedSupplier = cboJobSupplier.Text;
            List<Supplier> foundSup = Program.AuspexDo.SelectSupplier(selectedSupplier);

            //For the supplier found, find the part to be added
            foreach (Supplier s in foundSup)
            {
                string selectedPart = cboJobParts.Text;
                List<Part> foundPart = s.SelectPart(selectedPart);

                //Get those part details

                //Add those details to the job

                j.AddParts //the part item here from the supplier list;


            }                   
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: So what isn't working?  What aspect of this problem don't you know how to do?  How close is your current solution to solving the problem?

Comment: Not too sure what's being asked here... Did you have any problems implementing this code?

Comment: I dont know what your code is intended to do, but assigning to `foundSup` and `foundPart` everytime in a foreach looks so wrong to me.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do (difficult to understand what is the part item from the supplier list without seeing the code), but looks like you could do some SelectMany on all the suppliers parts and AddRange.

Comment: The thing I can't do is add an existing part item, into the job list. the part item exists in the supplier, so I need to take it from there and copy it into job? Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just change the `AddParts` method to (and call it `AddPart` since it adds only one part at a time):

```
public void AddPart(Part part)
{          
    m_partUsed.Add(part);         
}
```

You can then add a part with

```
j.AddPart(somePart);
```

or using an object initializer

```
j.AddPart(new Part{Num=PartNum, Name=PartName, Description=PartDescription,
                   Cost=Cost, Price=Price, Quantity=Quantity});
```

or using a constructor

```
j.AddPart(new Part(PartNum, PartName, PartDescription,
                   Cost, Price, Quantity));
```

---

If you prefer to keep your originial implementation you can have two `AddPart` methods side-by-side. This is called method overloading. You can then choose to add a part object or individual part values.

```
public void AddPart(Part part) { ... }
public void AddPart(int PartNum, string PartName,
                    string PartDescription, decimal Cost,
                    decimal CostWithVAT, decimal Price, short Quantity) { ... }
```

You can have as many methods with the same name as you want, as long as their parameter lists differ. Either the number of parameters must be different or the parameter types must be different. The parameter names are not taken into account.

Comment: I feel like that first bit is where I need to be going but the problem I'm having is that it's saying I can't pass a list item through that AddPart parameter. I'm going to have to come back to this later, I've been trying all afternoon, I'm sure after a break what you've put will just fall into place and I can get it working. thanks.

Comment: It looks like the statement `List<Part> foundPart = s.SelectPart(selectedPart);` is wrong. Souldn't it be `Part foundPart = s.SelectPart(selectedPart);`?

Comment: I don't think so, select part returns a list:                           `public List<Part> SelectPart(String PartRef)
        {
            List<Part> PartSet = new List<Part>();

            foreach (Part p in m_supplierParts)
            {
                if (p.PartNumber.ToString().Equals(PartRef, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    PartSet.Add(p);
            }

            return PartSet;
        }`

Comment: Then it should be called `SelectParts`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

```
m_partUsed.AddRange(foundPart)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `AddParts` creates a new Part. I would change this method so it would take a Part parameter that is then aded to the List.

```
public void AddParts(Part p)
{          
    m_partUsed.Add(p);         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
j.AddParts(foundSup.SelectMany(s => s.SelectPart(selectedPart)))
```

While AddParts would look like Alexei answer.

Answer (score 1):

IF I understood OP correctly he wants to add list to lists, ...

well I don't know about C# but I know about Unity C#

I quickly made it for you:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; // THIS one is very important since it contains the List

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
    List<int> ListOfIntegers = new List<int>();
    List<int> ListOfIntegers1 = new List<int>();
    List<List<int>> ListOfLists = new List<List<int>>();


    void Start(){
        ListOfIntegers.Add(1);
        ListOfIntegers1.Add(10);
        ListOfLists.Add(ListOfIntegers1);
        ListOfLists.Add(ListOfIntegers);
        Debug.Log((ListOfLists[0])[0]); // you get debug 10
    }
}
```

allso it reads it correctly I checked ;)

I hope this is useful. to non Unity C#